# Recact state is not being updated when using socket.io and react hooks

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-effect, use-state

I have a component like below.

```js
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import {Marker} from "react-map-gl";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { BASE_URL } from "../../../config/urls";
const socket = io(BASE_URL, {
    query: {
      token:
        "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXV",
    },
  });

export default function Route(){
    const [markerPos, setMarkerPos] = useState({
        longitude:8.5455940,latitude:47.3977421
    })
    const update=(data)=>{
        const obj = {
            longitude:data['gps.lon'],
            latitude:data['gps.lat']
        }
        setMarkerPos(prevProps =>{
            return {...prevProps,longitude:obj.longitude,latitude:obj.latitude}
        });
        console.log(markerPos.longitude,data['gps.lon'])
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on("mission_data",(socketData)=>{
            update(socketData)
        })
    },[])

    return null;
}
```

When visited some of the questions on StackOverflow, i came to this solution.

Questions:

[Why is my state not being updated using React Hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785673/why-is-my-state-not-being-updated-using-react-hooks)

[React State is not updated with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370656/react-state-is-not-updated-with-socket-io)

[React Hooks: state not updating when called inside Socket.io handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096828/react-hooks-state-not-updating-when-called-inside-socket-io-handler)

[React State is not updated with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370656/react-state-is-not-updated-with-socket-io)

`socket.on` is being called only once.
Although, `socketData` always gets updated. Every time new data is coming from `socket.io`.

[image: image of problem]

You can see in the image above, right side data which is **red**  colored is coming from the socket and it is updating. But, the left side data which is **green** colored is the react state variable is not updating.

Edit

this question is not a duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately).

I know react asynchronously update state. So, the state update will not reflect immediately.

In my case, the state is not updated even, I wait for an hour.

Comment: Probably wouldn't include your API token in publicly posted code...

Comment: @Matt i had removed about 10 to 12 characters of `API`, so, i don't this can create any issue.

Comment: "In my case, the state is not updated even, I wait for an hour." – that doesn't make any sense. Of course it's updated, you're just not printing it anywhere when it updates.

Comment: @GuyIncognito `not printing it anywhere` i am printing it on console, see `console.log(markerPos.longitude,data['gps.lon'])`

Comment: Yes. You're printing it *before it has updated*. You're not printing it *after* it has updated.

Comment: @GuyIncognito thanks for your time and effort, it worked by using the correct marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of markerPos is updated asynchronously. Try rendering MarkerPos and you should see it changing. If you want to call function when it changes, use another useEffect hook

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import {Marker} from "react-map-gl";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { BASE_URL } from "../../../config/urls";
const socket = io(BASE_URL, {
    query: {
      token:
        "xxxxxxx",
    },
  });

export default function Route(){
    const [markerPos, setMarkerPos] = useState({
        longitude:8.5455940,latitude:47.3977421
    })
    const update=(data)=>{
        const obj = {
            longitude:data['gps.lon'],
            latitude:data['gps.lat']
        }
        setMarkerPos(prevProps =>{
            return {...prevProps,longitude:obj.longitude,latitude:obj.latitude}
        });
        console.log(markerPos.longitude,data['gps.lon'])
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on("mission_data",(socketData)=>{
            update(socketData)
        })
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
       console.log(markerPos)
    },[markerPos])
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Here, we are listing change `markerPos`,i don't this will work. But, i am trying this.

Comment: In your component, the Route component is not rerendering, because props are not chaning, so there is no need to update the markerPos state, since it is not used